# Can I change the amount of a Stripe transfer?

Tags: stripe-payments

With the Stripe API I can [create a Transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create) to send money to a custom account.
In the API docs I see a way to [update a transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/update?lang=dotnet), but it doesn't look like I can change the amount of the transfer?

Can anyone acknowledge if this is correct?
It looks like I might have to [reverse the transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfer_reversals) and then create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to update the amount of Transfer after it's been created. The funds have moved from your account's balance to the connected account's balance already. If you wanted to transfer more, you can either create a second transfer for the difference, or reverse it and created a new one for the correct amount.

Comment: If I wanted to cancel it, would I just reverse it for the whole amount or not use any amount? The docs say by default the whole amount is reversed.

Comment: Correct, you reverse and don't pass `amount` and it does the right thing. Really easy to test all of this in their Test mode environment in a few seconds to confirm!